# Unable to upload file using rest service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, file-upload

I did a sample application for upload a file using restwebserivce.
This is not Maven project.only sample project.
here is web.xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>JAX RS Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.eb.rajesign.util</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is HTML code :

```
<body>
 <form action="resource/restwb/upload" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">
     File : <input type="file" name="upload" size="50" />
  <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

And java file :

```
package com.eb.rajesign.util;
 @Path("/restwb")
 public class FileResource {

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("upload") InputStream is, @FormDataParam("upload") FormDataContentDisposition formData) {
    System.out.println("I am in service");
    String fileLocation = "D:/TestRaj/" + formData.getFileName();

    try {
        saveFile(is, fileLocation);
        String result = "Successfully File Uploaded on the path " + fileLocation;
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(result).build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();

    }

}

private void saveFile(InputStream is, String fileLocation) throws IOException {

    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileLocation));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    int bytes = 0;
    while ((bytes = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
    }
}}
```

and i have added jar files list :

jersey-bundle-1.6.jar
jersey-core-1.18.jar
jersey-multipart-1.18.1.jar
jersey-server-1.18.1.jar
jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar
mimepull-1.9.3.jar
jersey-bundle-1.14.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar

i am not able to upload file.Can u please suggest me?
getting error : 
     [11/18/15 22:18:40:147 IST] 00000215 ServletWrappe E       com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
**[11/18/15 22:18:40:147 IST] 00000215 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[REST Service]: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class com/sun/jersey/spi/scanning/AnnotationScannerListener illegally accessing "private" member of class com/sun/jersey/core/reflection/ReflectionHelper
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.(AnnotationScannerListener.java:92)**